# Stochastic processes and random times

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X_n$ be a stochastic process, and $T$ an $\mathbb{N}_0$-valued random variable which is independent of the $X_n$. Then conditioning on the values of $T$ leads to
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_T\in A)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n\in A)\mathbb{P}(T=n) $$

Now suppose that $\{X_t:t\in[0,\infty)\}$ is a continuous-time process such that $(t,\omega)\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is measurable, and that $T$ is a $[0,\infty)$-valued random variable which is independent of the $X_t$. The analogue of the above formula is then
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_T\in A)=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_t\in A)dF_T(t) $$

What conditions on $X_t$ and $T$ are necessary to ensure that this identity holds? I tried approximating $T$ with discrete random variables, but it wasn't clear to me that things would work out in the limit. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$ B := \{(t, \omega) : X_t(\omega) \in A \}, $$
then
$$ \{X_T \in A\} = (T, \def\id{\mathrm{id}}\id)^{-1}[B] $$
where $(T, \id) \colon \Omega \to [0,\infty) \times \Omega$ denotes the function $(T,\id)(\omega) = \bigl(T(\omega), \omega\bigr)$. We have by Fubini
\begin{align*}
   \def\P{\mathbf P}\P(X_T \in A) &= \P\bigl((T,\id)^{-1}[B]\bigr)\\
     &= \P_{(T, \id)}(B)\\
     &= \int_{[0, \infty) \times \Omega} \chi_B(t, \omega) \,d\P_{(T,\id)}\\
     &= \int_{[0,\infty) \times \Omega} \chi_B(t,\omega)\, d(\P_T \times \P)\\
     &= \int_{[0,\infty)} \int_\Omega \chi_B(t,\omega)\, d\P(\omega)\, d\P_T(t)\\
     &= \int_{[0,\infty)} \P(X_t \in A)\, d\P_T(t)
\end{align*}

Comment: The index in the first line should be $\mathbf P(X_T \in A)$ and not $\mathbf P(X_t \in A)$.

Comment: @mag Thx, corrected.